# How to refactor the way of getting multiple @Value from a properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to get some values from aplication.properties file and these values depend on the country, for instance these are the below values that I need to fetch:

```
@Value("${fr.Name}")
private String frName;

@Value("${fr.address}")
private String frAddress;

@Value("${de.Name}")
private String deName;

@Value("${de.address}")
private String deAddress;

@Value("${bz.Name}")
private String bzName;

@Value("${bz.address}")
private String bzAddress;
```

Then in my service method, I will be using multiple if else statement and my list of values keep increasing each time I add new country

```
  public String apply(string country){
    if ("fr".equals(country))
       return frName + frAddress 
    else if ("de".equals(country))
       return deName + deAddress 
    else if ("bz".equals(country))
       return bzName + bzAddress 
}
```

So how can I refactor it without using multiple if-else statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at spring configuration properties. this gives an opportunity to handle configuration properties more declarative way
https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

EDIT

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my", ignoreUnknownFields = false)

public class CountryBasedProps {

    Map<String,CountryProps> config = new HashMap<>();


    public Map<String, CountryProps> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(Map<String, CountryProps> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public static class CountryProps{
        String name;
        String address;

        /*
           other properties, with getters/setters
         */

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CountryProps{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CountryBasedProps{" +
                "config=" + config +
                '}';
    }
}
```

properties:

```
my.config.fr.name=French
my.config.fr.address=Paris
my.config.de.name=German
my.config.de.address=Berlin
```

output

```
CountryBasedProps{config={fr=CountryProps{name='French', address='Paris'}, de=CountryProps{name='German', address='Berlin'}}}
```

Note:

add `@EnableConfigurationProperties()` into your project

Comment: but I will keep defining multiple @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "de") for each country

Comment: create shared prefix myconfiguration.de.name, myconfiguration.de.address. and you will need @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myconfiguration") only

Comment: @DALDOUL added an example

Answer (score 1):

[2.7.1. Loading YAML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml)

You can load the configuration file directly into `Map` using `@ConfigurationProperties` and then get the corresponding value with respective key. So you can avoid using `if` block

**application.yml** If you are using `application.yml`

```
countries:
  fr: fnamefaddress
  de: dnamedaddress
  bz: bnamebaddress
```

**application.properties :** If you are using `application.properties`

```
countries.fr=fnamefaddress
countries.de=dnamedaddress
countries.be=bnamebaddress
```

**Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class CountriesConfig {

   @Getter
   private Map<String, String> countries = new HashMap<String, String>();

}
```

**output :**

```
{bz=bnamebaddress, de=dnamedaddress, fr=fnamefaddress}
```

So in code you can simply use `get` or `getOrDefault` on `Map`

```
countries.get("fr");
```